# Please remove the daily reputation gap

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Call me anal, but this recently introduced `margin-bottom:15px;` in `#subheader` on the questions list is really disturbing me. Okay, maybe I'd get used to it, but then at least <strike>do it on all four sites, and don't leave out Stack Overflow.</strike>* line it up with the summary count ("10,560 questions").

<sub>*It's on all sites now</sub>

In case you're doing A/B testing – put me in the "against" column.

[image: Donkey]

Comment: It's the gap I have to look at when picking up my daily dose of reputation -- in case you wanted to ask.

Comment: +1 for using "anal" and "gap" in the same question.

Comment: @Pekka: I'm not sure I want that upvote...

Comment: I'd -1 for the orange juice that I now have all over my computer, but +1 for Donkey Kong overrides that.

Comment: Do I get a reward for calling you "anal", or am I expected to do it pro bono?

Comment: @balpha you need to see it as a +1 for hilariousness. It's, hrm,  *cavitally* funny.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, this should be fixed on meta and will be rolled out to the other sites shortly.

Just doing some HTML / CSS cleanup to prepare us for the set of 10 mini-CSS Zen Garden designs that @jzy and @nathanbowers are working on.

Comment: Yep, that looks a lot better. Thanks.